# return array of windows registry key subkeys c++

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

i have this code in a c void function to get and print subkeys of a windows registry key

```
TCHAR    achKey[MAX_KEY_LENGTH];   // buffer for subkey name
retCode = RegQueryInfoKey(
        hKey,                    // key handle 
        achClass,                // buffer for class name 
        &cchClassName,           // size of class string 
        NULL,                    // reserved 
        &cSubKeys,               // number of subkeys 
        &cbMaxSubKey,            // longest subkey size 
        &cchMaxClass,            // longest class string 
        &cValues,                // number of values for this key 
        &cchMaxValue,            // longest value name 
        &cbMaxValueData,         // longest value data 
        &cbSecurityDescriptor,   // security descriptor 
        &ftLastWriteTime);       // last write time 

    // Enumerate the subkeys, until RegEnumKeyEx fails.

    if (cSubKeys)
    {
        printf( "\nNumber of subkeys: %d\n", cSubKeys);

        for (i=0; i<cSubKeys; i++) 
        { 
            cbName = MAX_KEY_LENGTH;
            retCode = RegEnumKeyEx(hKey, i,
                     achKey, 
                     &cbName, 
                     NULL, 
                     NULL, 
                     NULL, 
                     &ftLastWriteTime); 
            if (retCode == ERROR_SUCCESS) 
            {
                _tprintf(TEXT("(%d) %s\n"), i+1, achKey);
            }
        }
    }
```

how can i modify  to return an array with all the subkeys values
thanks

---

hi david thanks for your response,
i'am not able to compile without errors using `vector<string> subkeys`,
with these headers

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
```

if i change to:

```
vector<TCHAR> getSubKeys(HKEY key)
{
    vector<TCHAR>> subkeys;
    ....
    for (i=0; i<cSubKeys; i++) 
    {
        // get subkey name
        subkeys.push_back(TCHAR>(achKey));
    }
    ....
    return subkeys;
}
```

with this change it works but at t_main function when i try to list the vector to the console just show eight(the number of subkeys is correct) numbers like 65000 the same value for the eight vector elements, where's the problem or how can i compile with your code,
thanks a lot

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: nothing i'm starting with win32

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are using C++, you should not be using arrays. Instead `vector<T>` is the appropriate data structure. Create one of these to hold your registry key strings.

```
vector<string> subkeys;
```

Where you currently print `achKey`, instead add to `subkeys`:

```
subkeys.push_back(string(achKey));
```

If you are building for Unicode, then use `wstring` instead.

Your function might look like this:

```
vector<string> getSubKeys(HKEY key)
{
    vector<string> subkeys;
    ....
    for (i=0; i<cSubKeys; i++) 
    {
        // get subkey name
        subkeys.push_back(string(achKey));
    }
    ....
    return subkeys;
}
```